# SyntaxHighlighter Evolved 3.2.1 plugin Converted "<" to &amp;lt;

Tags: wordpress, syntaxhighlighter

I am facing problem with SyntaxHighlighter Evolved 3.2.1 (Latest Version). If my code consists of "<" sign, it converting as &lt;.

I am using the SyntaxHighlighter shot codes like :

```
[sourecode language="java"]
<Cricketer>
[/sourcecode]
```

Its converting like below :

```
&amp;lt;Cricketer&amp;gt;
```

I have also tried

```
[java]
<Cricketer>
[/java]
```

Can any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try in **functions.php**:

```
function mihdan_fix_syntaxhighlighter( $html ) {
    return preg_replace( '/&amp;([^;]+;)/', '&$1', $html );
}
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'mihdan_fix_syntaxhighlighter' );
add_filter( 'syntaxhighlighter_htmlresult', 'mihdan_fix_syntaxhighlighter' );
add_filter( 'syntaxhighlighter_precode', 'mihdan_fix_syntaxhighlighter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the text editor not the visual editor.

As per the plugin description - Easily post syntax-highlighted code to your site without having to modify the code at all. Uses Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter. TIP: Don't use the Visual editor if you don't want your code mangled. TinyMCE will "clean up" your HTML.